# JSON to generate app dmg

Tags: json, macos, dmg

I'm trying to find an automatic way to generate at dmg file with my app inside and a nice looking background and application icon. I have found a an app which generate this called appdmg

https://www.npmjs.com/package/appdmg

My issue is that the json file is not understand and still complaining about a syntax issue.

Any example I found matching my syntax..

```
{
    "title": "myApp",
    "icon": "icon.ico",
    "background": "banner.png",
    "icon-size": 80,
    "contents": [
        { "x": 192, "y": 344, "type": "link", "path": "/Applications" },
        { "x": 448, "y": 344, "type": "file", "path": “connect.app” }
    ]
}
```

Any idea or other easy cli tool ? I need to plug the tool inside a build server which generate automatically the app.

Thanks

Comment: Are those curly quotes around `“connect.app”` ?

Answer (score 0):

Curly quotes are your syntax error. "connect.app" vs. “connect.app”